# Is there an AngularJS module similar to NodeJS request library?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, node.js, http

Greetings overflowers,

I am looking for an AngularJS module that simplifies HTTP/HTTPS requests with some extras similar to the popular request library for NodeJS (https://github.com/request/request)

The default $http is using promises which are rather verbous in comparison to simple callbacks with err/results paramters.

I am also looking for a simpler way to manually abort the AJAX requests.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's verbose about the promise method?

Comment: When don't want to use `$http` module there is well known [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular). Now telling you it is exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: Are you sure that Rectangular is using simple callbacks with error and results parameters rather than promises?

Comment: @Brad You need to register 2 callbacks for success and errors + not easy to abort requests manually + does not come with extra functionality like NodeJS request's qs, form, oauth... etc. stuff which I need

Comment: @geeko No you don't.  You can use `.always()`.  And, aborting is the same as anything else.  And finally, using Angular doesn't prohibit you from using those modules from Node.js.  Check out Browserify to bundle your application.

Comment: @Brad Thanks buddy for the useful info. Does always/finally get error and results parameters? because this is what I need. Browserify is nice but would be an overkill for what I am asking. Aborting in other libraries is simply a returned function from calling get/post that you can call to manually abort the AJAX request. Is it the same with $http?

Comment: @geeko It should.  I'm not an Angular guy so I haven't tried it, but it's following the standard promise methods so you should have all that you need in there.  See also:  https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback

Answer (score 2):

You can always make your own wrapper-service and deal with the promises only inside:

```
app.service('myHttpService', function($http){
   this.get = function(url, successCb, errorCb){
         var promise = $http.get(url);
         promise.success(successCb);
         promise.error(errorCb);
   };
   // delete, put, post etc..
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to leverage an existing wrapper library if exists.